# string не реализует интерфейс Stringer golang

Tags: строки, golang, интерфейс

Допустим я хочу написать функцию конкатенации строк и любых других объектов, приводимых к строкам. Хотел я написать это вот так:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func concatenate(s1 fmt.Stringer, s2 fmt.Stringer) string {
    return s1.String() + s2.String()
}

func main() {
    concatenate("q", "w")
}
```

Но обнаружил, что `string` не реализует интерфейс `Stringer`

В связи с этим возникает 2 вопроса

1. Можно ли реализовать мою задумку красиво? Я придумал такой вариант:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

type StringStringer struct {
    value string
}

func (str StringStringer) String() string {
    return str.value
}

func concatenate(s1 fmt.Stringer, s2 fmt.Stringer) string {
    return s1.String() + s2.String()
}

func main() {
    s1 := StringStringer{"q"}
    s2 := StringStringer{"w"}
    concatenate(s1, s2)
}
```

Но все-таки получается как-будто лишний код, мне это не очень нравиться.

2. Почему разработчики `go` не добавили метод `String()` к строкам? Мне кажется это было бы очень логично, хотя я, конечно, могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни один из встроенных типов в Go не имеет методов. Для того, чтобы `string` удовлетворял интерфейсу `fmt.Stringer`, нужно к типу `string` добавить метод `String`. Тогда сразу возникнет вопрос - какие ещё методы можно добавить? А почему методы добавляются только к `string`? От этого посыпится вся система встроенных типов.

Ваш тип `StringStringer` можно упростить:

```
type StringStringer string

func (s StringStringer) String() string { return string(s) }
```

В этом случае достаточно делать приведение типа

```
    s1, s2 := "q", "w"
    s := Concat(
        StringStringer(s1),
        StringStringer(s2),
    )
```

Ну и саму функцию конкатенации можно сделать с переменным числом аргументов

```
func Concat(objects ...fmt.Stringer) string {
    var builder strings.Builder
    for _, obj := range objects {
        builder.WriteString(obj.String())
    }
    return builder.String()
}
```

Полный пример https://go.dev/play/p/_EYgKsuQLat